# What is the purpose of ScheduledFuture.get() method if is retrieved from the scheduleWithFixedDelay/scheduleAtFixedRate method

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am confused with the following.

I know, if I use the `schedule` method from the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = 
scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(myClassRunnable, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am able to retrieve later the *value* through
`scheduledFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` or `scheduledFuture.get()` and it should be `null` because the task has been executed just only once and it is completed.
And `null` because I am working with the `Runnable` `schedule` method version and not with the `Callable` `schedule` method version. It according with the API.

Until here I am fine.

My question:

What is the purpose of `ScheduledFuture` if is retrieved from the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` (even from `scheduleAtFixedRate`) method:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture= 
scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(myClassRunnable, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Yes, I know both *fixed* methods execute the same task many times until the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's shutdown` method is called (it must stop all the tasks scheduled).

I did a research through Google looking for some examples using `ScheduledFuture` returned from `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, I only found one using the **cancel** method, to cancel a specific task. But none working with `get()`.

I don't know if I am wrong, but seems useless the `get()` method if we are working with `scheduleWithFixedDelay`, because if I use later:

- `scheduledFuture.get()` - it remains awaiting and the `Runnable` object remains working many times (run,complete,delay,run,etc... )
- `scheduledFuture.get(32, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` - always gives a `TimeoutException`

I thought I should be able to retrieve the `null` value since I can use the `period` argument/parameter from the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method. I.e: Run the `Runnable object`, wait until it completes and use the `scheduledFuture.get()` to get the `null` value that confirms it has been completed, await the period of the delay time to run again the `Runnable` object according with the `period` value etc....

Clarifications and examples are totally welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ScheduledFuture can be used to get time left before next task execution:

```
    ScheduledFuture<?> f = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run");
        }
    }, 0, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Time left before next run " + f.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

prints

```
run
Time left before next run 8999
```

Comment: Thanks by the reply and code, ok has sense, just curious if you have a case where the ScheduledFuture's **get** method would be used with scheduleAtFixedRate/scheduleWithFixedDelay. Thank You.

Comment: Does not really answer to the OP question `What is the purpose of ScheduledFuture.get() method`

Answer (score 2):

I tried this out with the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
Runnable task = () -> {
    int currentCount = count.incrementAndGet();
    System.out.println("Task #" + currentCount + " started");
    if (currentCount == 2) {
        System.out.println("Shutting down scheduler...");
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ie);
    }
    System.out.println("Task #" + currentCount + " finished");
};

System.out.println("Starting scheduler...");
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
    task, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Getting scheduled future...");
System.out.println(scheduledFuture.get());        
System.out.println("End of code reached.");
```

Here is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at Rextester.main(source.java:33)
Starting scheduler...
Getting scheduled future...
Task #1 started
Task #1 finished
Task #2 started
Shutting down scheduler...
Task #2 finished
```

**Online Rextester Demo:** https://rextester.com/LYKN32123

Not sure how useful this is but it shows the `get()` method throws a `CancellationException` if the scheduler is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that in the case of using `.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)` (or `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`), the `get()` method of the returned `ScheduledFuture<?>` feels indeed as an odd fit.

I believe you won't ever receive anything from the `get()` method, just expect an exception to be thrown from it, when Runnable is cancelled.

Surely one can see a use-case for this ;-)

see JavaDoc

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

> Returns:
>   a ScheduledFuture representing pending completion of the task, and whose get() method will throw an exception upon cancellation

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch the exception thrown by the submitted task without calling `get`.

Suppose you have a task like this.

```java
public class Task1 implements Runnable {
    private int counter = 3;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("It is called");
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException(new Exception("It fails"));
        }
    }
}
```

No exception is thrown by the following code, so you are not able to handle that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Task1 task1 = new Task1();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

However, if you add `get` to it, then you can catch the exception.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Task1 task1 = new Task1();
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        future.get();  // CAUTION: This line blocks the execution
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using scheduledFuture.get() you can get a handle to the task, and in case this task needs to be cancelled say manually from the UserInterface or based on some conditions like the null, the handle can be used to cancel it.

Comment: `scheduledFuture.cancel(bool)` is what is used to cancel the `Runnable`